# How do I add a search for the next match?

Tags: vba, excel, find

I need to search for items and when found the match, put them into the userform. I could do the search when pressing the search button, but could not manage to search the next match when pressing the same button again(*CommandButton4*).

I'd like to find all matches by pressing the button until nothing further found. Here are my codes:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BİLGİLER")

FindString = TextBox2.Value

If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
    Set Rng = ws.Cells.Find( _
                     What:=FindString, _
                     LookIn:=xlValues, _
                     LookAt:=xlPart, _
                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                     SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                     MatchCase:=False, _
                     SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto Rng, True

        TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
        TextBox2.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
        ComboBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        TextBox3.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        TextBox4.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
        TextBox5.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
        TextBox6.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
        TextBox7.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
        ComboBox2.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
        TextBox8.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
        TextBox9.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value

        TextBox10.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15).Value
        TextBox11.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16).Value
        TextBox12.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17).Value
        TextBox13.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18).Value
        TextBox14.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 19).Value
        TextBox15.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 20).Value
        TextBox16.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21).Value
        TextBox17.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 22).Value
        ComboBox3.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23).Value
        TextBox18.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24).Value
        TextBox19.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 25).Value

        TextBox20.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value
        TextBox21.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Value
        TextBox22.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12).Value
        TextBox23.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Value
        TextBox24.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Value

        ComboBox4.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26).Value
        ComboBox5.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 27).Value

        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select         
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing found"
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

I know it mustn't be so hard but my brain has stopped working. :) I've done so much search that I can't even think now... Thanks in advance.

Comment: What column are you searching?

Comment: In TextBox2, there is name and surname. Its value goes to column C. When I enter some part of a name (say the first 3 letters) in the textbox on the userform and press the button it should find the fisrt match, then when I pressed the button again it should find the next match and so on.

Answer (score 0):

please put following loop in the end of your code to find all other matches:

```
dim sFirstMatchAddress as string
sFirstMatchAddress  = Rng.address

With ws.Cells

  Do
    Set rng = .FindNext(rng)
    If sFirstMatchAddress = rng.Address Then Exit Do
    'Fill the text boxes*
  Loop  

end with
```

Also, I guess it will be impossible to predict how may textboxes you require to handle all matches. You may need to think how to add textboxes dynamically depanding on number of matches.

Secondly, you don't have to use

```
Application.Goto Rng, True
```

and

```
TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
```

Instead, put only:

```
TextBox1.Value = Rng.Offset(0, -1).Value
```

Comment: I think you should test for `sFirstMatchAddress` **before** you fill the textboxes.  And since you are not changing any of the matched addresses, `Rng is Nothing` should never be true

Comment: Look closely at your edits.  I would suggest `Do: Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng): If sFirstMatchAddress = Rng.Address then Exit Do:  *Fill the text boxes* : Loop`

Answer (score 0):

Worksheets("BILGILER") has to be the ActiveSheet because you are selecting cells on it.

### Tried and Tested

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

    Dim FindString As String
    Dim Rng As Range, SearchRange As Range

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BILGILER").Select

    Set SearchRange = Intersect(Columns("C"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)


    FindString = TextBox2.Value

    If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
        Set Rng = SearchRange.Find( _
                  What:=FindString, _
                  After:=Cells(ActiveCell.Row, "C"), _
                  LookIn:=xlValues, _
                  LookAt:=xlPart, _
                  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                  SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                  MatchCase:=False, _
                  SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng, True

                    TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
                    TextBox2.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
                    ComboBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                    TextBox3.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                    TextBox4.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
                    TextBox5.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
                    TextBox6.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
                    TextBox7.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value
                    ComboBox2.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value
                    TextBox8.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value
                    TextBox9.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value

                    TextBox10.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15).Value
                    TextBox11.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 16).Value
                    TextBox12.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17).Value
                    TextBox13.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 18).Value
                    TextBox14.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 19).Value
                    TextBox15.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 20).Value
                    TextBox16.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21).Value
                    TextBox17.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 22).Value
                    ComboBox3.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23).Value
                    TextBox18.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 24).Value
                    TextBox19.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 25).Value

                    TextBox20.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value
                    TextBox21.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Value
                    TextBox22.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 12).Value
                    TextBox23.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13).Value
                    TextBox24.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 14).Value

                    ComboBox4.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26).Value
                    ComboBox5.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 27).Value

            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Thomas but it di not work. :(

Comment: This code finds the first matching record when hit the button but when I hit the button again it does not find the next match. When I entered the criterion into the textbox on the userform 'again' it finds the next match. For example, I want to find a name beginning with "GA". When I entered "GA" in the textbox on the userform and I hit the search button, it finds the first match but it does not find the next match when hit the button again. I have to put "GA" again into the textbox on the userform in order to find the next match.

Comment: The code does a partial search based on `TextBox2.Value`.  As per your orginal code `TextBox2.Value` is set to the value of the found cell.  The next time you click the search string it will search based on the new criteria.

Comment: Yep, that's right. :) I put a new textbox and made the search from there. Thus, every time I hit the button the userform is filled in with the info of the next match. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Markos, I did what you said; I put the edited code. It is like this now:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BİLGİLER")

FindString = TextBox2.Value

If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
Set Rng = ws.Cells.Find( _
                 What:=FindString, _
                 LookIn:=xlValues, _
                 LookAt:=xlPart, _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                 SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                 MatchCase:=False, _
                 SearchFormat:=False)

If Not Rng Is Nothing Then

Dim sFirstMatchAddress As String
sFirstMatchAddress = Rng.Address

With ws.Cells

Do
Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
If sFirstMatchAddress = Rng.Address Then Exit Do

    TextBox1.Value = Rng.Offset(0, -1).Value
    TextBox2.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 0).Value
    ComboBox1.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
    TextBox3.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
    TextBox4.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 3).Value
    TextBox5.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 4).Value
    TextBox6.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 5).Value
    TextBox7.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 6).Value
    ComboBox2.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 7).Value
    TextBox8.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 8).Value
    TextBox9.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 9).Value

    TextBox10.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 15).Value
    TextBox11.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 16).Value
    TextBox12.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 17).Value
    TextBox13.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 18).Value
    TextBox14.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 19).Value
    TextBox15.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 20).Value
    TextBox16.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 21).Value
    TextBox17.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 22).Value
    ComboBox3.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 23).Value
    TextBox18.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 24).Value
    TextBox19.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 25).Value

    TextBox20.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 10).Value
    TextBox21.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 11).Value
    TextBox22.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 12).Value
    TextBox23.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 13).Value
    TextBox24.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 14).Value

    ComboBox4.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 26).Value
    ComboBox5.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 27).Value
    Loop

End With

Else
    MsgBox "Nothing found"
End If
End If

End Sub
```

But it did not work, either. It does what my previous code does; it finds only one match. I don't know if I put them in right place.

Correction: It does not what my previous code does; it finds the **last** match.

Comment: hi, the reason why you see last match is because you put results of every match to same text boxes. As I mentioned, to see all the results you need to add a new set of textboxes every time you find matching cell.

Comment: Or please explain how you want to view multiple matches in the userForm?

Comment: Hmm... When I hit the search button it will find the first match according to the criterion entered in the textbox on the userform, and the info in the row of the criterion should be filled in on the userform. If the first match is not what I want, I will hit the search button again and it will find the next match and fill in the info in the related row and so on. By the way is it also possible to correct an entry on the userform after finding and fillin in the textboxes and comboboxes on the userform?

Comment: Ok, I think I know what you mean, don't have time now but will try to firure out something later if no one else answers. On the other hand, all you write can be easier done in MS Access.

Comment: MS Access scares me. :D I don't have time to learn, explore it now. Furthermore, the users of this Excel file are not even aware of Access. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this. It only reads data to user form.

```
 Option Explicit

Private rngLastFound As Range

Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range, SearchRange As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BILGILER")
If rngLastFound Is Nothing Then Set rngLastFound = ws.Range("C1")
Set SearchRange = Intersect(Columns("C"), ws.UsedRange)

FindString = TextBox2.Value

If Trim(FindString) <> vbNullString Then
    Set Rng = SearchRange.Find( _
                     What:=FindString, _
                     After:=ws.Cells(rngLastFound.Row, SearchRange.Column), _
                     LookIn:=xlValues, _
                     LookAt:=xlPart, _
                     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                     SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                     MatchCase:=False, _
                     SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Set rngLastFound = Rng

        TextBox1.Value = Rng.Offset(0, -1).Value
        TextBox2.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 0).Value
        ComboBox1.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
        TextBox3.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 2).Value
        TextBox4.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 3).Value
        TextBox5.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 4).Value
        TextBox6.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 5).Value
        TextBox7.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 6).Value
        ComboBox2.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 7).Value
        TextBox8.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 8).Value
        TextBox9.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 9).Value

        TextBox10.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 15).Value
        TextBox11.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 16).Value
        TextBox12.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 17).Value
        TextBox13.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 18).Value
        TextBox14.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 19).Value
        TextBox15.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 20).Value
        TextBox16.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 21).Value
        TextBox17.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 22).Value
        ComboBox3.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 23).Value
        TextBox18.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 24).Value
        TextBox19.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 25).Value

        TextBox20.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 10).Value
        TextBox21.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 11).Value
        TextBox22.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 12).Value
        TextBox23.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 13).Value
        TextBox24.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 14).Value

        ComboBox4.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 26).Value
        ComboBox5.Value = Rng.Offset(0, 27).Value

    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing found"
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Runtime Error '424' Object Required... Debug: If rngLastFound Is Nothing Then

Comment: did you add this declaration outside of procedure: `Private rngLastFound As Range` ??